# Using MarkdownSharp's markdown.cs in an ASPX file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set up a simple aspx page which demos the functionality of a c# class, MarkdownSharp. The class is in its own namespace in a separate .cs file. There is no vs project set up, just a standalone aspx file and a standalone .cs file.

In an `.aspx` file, i have set up a `Page` directive as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" codefile="~/bfadmin/aspx/Markdown.aspx.cs" Inherits="MarkdownSharp.Markdown" %>


<script runat="server" language="c#">

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var md = new Markdown();
    string html = md.Transform("*3234*");
    Response.Write(html);   

    }
</script>
```

The codeFile is wrapped in a namespace as follows (full file here: https://github.com/balpha/markdownsharp):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace MarkdownSharp
{
public class MarkdownOptions
{
...
}
public class Markdown 
{
...
}
}
```

When I run the aspx page, I get something like:

```
CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MarkdownSharp.Markdown'; another partial declaration of this type exists
```

Comment: try public partial class Markdown

Comment: did, and it then tells me that I have not referenced it properly in the aspx page "inherits" element

Comment: you need to do the same in the code behind too : public partial class MarkdownSharp.Markdown

Comment: Thats where I did it... but then it tells me that i've not used the proper value in the "inherits" attribute.